# Concurrency issues with ScriptManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, scriptmanager, clientscriptmanager

I know that Asp.Net WebForms is pretty old and obsolete, but I hope there are still people around maintaining such a legacy code base...

I'm seeing weird errors when load-testing our website, which all seem to boil down to concurrency issues in the way .Net handles the script references on the page. I can see reports of the problem dating back from 2007 here: [ScriptManager throws "An entry with the same key already exists."](https://forums.asp.net/t/1069753.aspx?ScriptManager%20throws%20An%20entry%20with%20the%20same%20key%20already%20exists%20).

I'm using .Net 4.7.2, and here is a sample of errors than occur under load:

**Error 1**
ArgumentException: An entry with the same key already exists.

```
   at System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary.Add(Object key, Object value)
   at System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.RegisterScriptBlock(ScriptKey key, String script, ListDictionary& scriptBlocks, ArrayList& scriptList, Boolean needsScriptTags)
   at System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.RegisterScriptBlock(ScriptKey key, String script, ClientAPIRegisterType type)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptRegistrationManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Control control, Type type, String key, String url)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptIncludeInternal(Control control, Type type, String key, String url)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterUniqueScripts(List'1 uniqueScripts)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts()
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

**Error 2**
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
   at System.Collections.Generic.List'1.Add(T item)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptRegistrationManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Control control, Type type, String key, String url)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptIncludeInternal(Control control, Type type, String key, String url)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterUniqueScripts(List'1 uniqueScripts)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts()
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

**Error 3**
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
   at System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.RenderRegisteredScripts(HtmlTextWriter writer, ArrayList scripts, Boolean checkForScriptManagerRegistrations)
   at System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.RenderClientScriptBlocks(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.BeginFormRender(HtmlTextWriter writer, String formUniqueID)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at ASP.masters_site_master.__RenderHtml(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Looking at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com) from .Net, the only possibility these errors might occur is with multi-thread. I see that some fields and methods are static inside `ScriptManager` and `ClientScriptManager` which may explain this, although I haven't found a sure scenario where concurrency would occur.

Has anyone seen, solved or workaround this problem?

Comment: How exactly are you seeing those errors? Does the page not load as a result? Are they logged to graylog or something similar? Something else?

Comment: it looks like ScriptManager is called inside a loop, that could explain the same key and out of bounds. But without some code there is not much we can do...

Comment: Just to clarify: 1/ this error is seen as an Application Error when loading the page. 2/ I'm not sure how I can show code, the callstack is 100% inside .Net's internal rendering events.